# Do child threads exit when the parent thread terminates

Tags: c++, windows

I was doing some multithreaded programming in Visual studio C++ using the calls beginthreadex, endthreadex.

I create a child thread thread1. The child thread runs on a function which never exits as it has an infinite loop. Now if the parent thread terminates with error or finishes successfully, does the child thread also exit? My doubt is - is there any situation where the child thread is alive even after the main program exits?

For linux how should this case be?

Comment: Here's a closely related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197699/is-it-necessary-to-explicitly-stop-all-threads-prior-to-exiting-a-win32-applicati

Comment: The post has conflicting answers.

Comment: @user97642  What are the conflicts from your point of view? The answers all seem to me to be similar.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

There is no parent/child relationship between threads. If thread A creates thread B and then thread A terminates, then thread B will continue to execute.

The exception to this is when the main thread (that is, the thread that runs the `main()` function) terminates. When this happens, the process terminates and all other threads stop.

Comment: Two exceptions. If *any* thread calls `exit`, then *all* threads terminate.

Comment: I would also like to add that if `main` exists without calling `detach` on the running thread, you will have an exception thrown.

Answer (score 10):

Since C and C++ [mandate that returning from the `main` function kills all running threads](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/08/27/10054832.aspx), yes, the process should be gone. And since that behavior is done by the runtime the situation should be the same on Linux.

Comment: The link you provided does not say anything about a language requirement of *killing* (!) all threads. It only cites a requirement that returning from main is equivalent to calling exit().

Comment: The link don't work now. Can you provide a newer one

Answer (score 2):

As soon as your process die, all the resources are being released (memory, files and threads)

The correct way to do this: when you call beginthread, keep the returned handle in the parent thread, and call **WaitForObject** before you leave the program (we *join* the parent thread with the child thread).

The parent thread will block until the child thread finish. If your child thread has a infinite loop, you could define an "interruption point" , and check if you should leave. For example, using a shared boolean variable. Check [Interrupt Politely](http://www.drdobbs.com/architecture-and-design/207100682) fro more info.

Comment: Your case is fine when the program normally terminates, that is it reaches end of main(). But there are many places in the primary or parent thread that call exit(). So would exit() kill all threads?

Comment: @user97642  If the main thread exits then all other threads stop

Comment: Be aware that infinite waits on semaphores, handles etc can cause your process to become a zombie in both Windows and Linux.  Otherwise it's as the others say; when the main thread dies, all others are killed.